# possibility for unitary CFTs?

Tags: symmetry, conformal-field-theory, lie-algebra

In all notes on conformal field theory, the unitarity bounds are obtained by requiring that we have a positive definite inner product. I get how this allows for a probabilistic interpretation, and unitarity is usually associated with the existence of a positive definite inner product.

But the important question is whether the conformal symmetry can be realized unitarily. The offending commutators from the conformal algebra that are worrying me are

$$[D,P_{\mu}]=iP_{\mu}, \quad [D,K_{\mu}]=-iK_{\mu}$$

These mean that $P_{\mu}$ and $K_{\mu}$ are ladder operators of $D$, which change the eigenvalues of $D$ by $\pm i$. No matter what then, this means that $D$ is not hermitian.

This is telling me that there exist no unitary representations of the conformal algebra. If this is not the case, I would like to understand why.

If it is the case, how are we able to consider the conformal algebra a symmetry of a quantum system? It is my understanding that symmetries must be realized in quantum mechanics by either unitary or antiunitary transformations. The nonhermiticity of the scaling generator means that a scaling transformation can be neither.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before we even start talking about ladder operators, there is a much simpler test. Consider that $P_\mu$ is Hermitian. (You might have seen the relation $P^\dagger_\mu=K_\mu$. This is a source of a lot of confusion, and I will comment on it later. For now, let's simply agree that $P_\mu$ is the usual momentum and thus certainly $P^\dagger_\mu=P_\mu$.)
Let's assume that $D$ is also Hermitian and try to check whether this is consistent with the commutation relation
$$
[D,P_\mu]=iP_\mu.
$$
Taking Hermitian conjugation on both sides, and using $[D,P_\mu]^\dagger=[P^\dagger_\mu, D^\dagger]$, we get
$$
[P_\mu,D]=-iP_\mu.
$$
This is consistent with the original commutation relation. On the other hand, had we assumed that $D$ is anti-Hermitian, then we would get a contradiction.

Now, we can go to the argument using ladder operators. You are saying that $D$ cannot be Hermitian for the following reason.

1. If $|\Psi\rangle$ is a normalizable eigenstate of $D$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $P_\mu|\Psi\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $D$ with eigenvalue $\lambda+i$.
2. Hermitian operators have real eigenvalues, but $\lambda$ and $\lambda+i$ cannot be real simultaneously.

Here I say "normalizable" because non-normalizable states are, well, not states. This argument doesn't work here, because it assumes that $D$ has normalizable eigenstates that are in the domain of $P_\mu$, and are not annihilated by $P_\mu$. This is apparently not true, at least I am not aware of any argument to the contrary. You could try to construct such states. E.g. if $\mathcal{O}(x)$ is a Hermitian primary operator, so $[D,\mathcal{O}(x)]=\Delta \mathcal{O}(x)$ for some real $\Delta$, you could try to define
$$
|\Psi\rangle = \mathcal{O}(0)|0\rangle.
$$
However, this is not a normalizable state, because its norm is
$$
\langle\Psi|\Psi\rangle = \langle 0|\mathcal{O}(0)\mathcal{O}(0)|0\rangle = \infty.
$$
(In our context $(\mathcal{O}(x))^\dagger=\mathcal{O}(x)$, without any inversion applied to $x$. This is related to $P^\dagger \neq K$ comment above. See about that below.) You could also try to patch the argument to work on the continuous spectrum of $D$ ("non-normalizable" eigenstates), but that will fail too. (You can ask a follow-up about that.)

Let me now address the issue about $P_\mu^\dagger\neq K_\mu$ and applying inversion when taking Hermitian conjugate of $\mathcal{O}(x)$. We use $P_\mu^\dagger = K_\mu$ and inversion when taking Hermitian conjugate of $\mathcal{O}(x)$ when we work in Euclidean signature, and in radial quantization. That is, after we have Wick-rotated to Euclidean *and* performed some further redefinitions to land in radial quantization. Doing this makes analysis of unitarity complicated. Wick-rotation introduces some $i$'s and going to radial quantization mixes them up in a way such that while we had hermitian $P_\mu$ in the beginning, we now have $P_\mu^\dagger = K_\mu$ in the end, etc. Also, after this $D$ is not what it used to be, and is in fact anti-Hermitian and has pure imaginary eigenvalues $i\Delta$.

Finally, it is worth stressing that the algebra of Hermitian conformal generators is $SO(2,d)$ (even in Euclidean signature) and its unitary representations are well-understood and classified. So even if you are not satisfied with this answer, rest assured that unitary representations of conformal symmetry do exist.

Comment: Of course, $|0\rangle$ is a normalizable eigenstate of $D$ which is in the range of $P_\mu$, but $P_\mu$ annihilates it, so there is no argument here.

Comment: In conformal field theories it is very frequently assumed that a dilatation eigenstate of the form you constructed has it's eigenvalue raised by 1 (or $i$) after acted on by $P_{\mu}$. Presumably based on what you said this is only well defined in the Wick rotated radially quantized theory?

Comment: Also, I would really like to understand more how the Wick rotation and different quantization affects the hermiticity of the generators and hwo this is all consistent. Do you have any references you would recommend on this?

Comment: @LucashWindowWasher Yes, when people write $\mathcal{O}(0)|0\rangle$ they have radial quantization in mind. You can read about Wick rotation in David Simmons-Duffin's lectures from TASI 2019. Radial quantization is a conformal transformation from quantizing in flat slices. Maybe Slava Rychkov's EPFL lectures have details.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk " is SO(2,d) (even in Euclidean signature) and its unitary representations are well-understood and classified." Can you provide me with a trustworthy (standard) reference where this is done explicitly?

Comment: @ungerade In CFT one is interested in unitary representations in which all states have positive energies. This is classified by Mack in 4d in https://inspirehep.net/literature/100788 . The result are the usual unitarity bounds that one derives assuming operator-state correspondence, so should generalize to any number of dimensions.If you are interested in all unitary representations (not just positive energy), then you'll have to look at math literature; I don't have a reference that jumps to my mind. For that you should take into account that we need the universal cover of $SO(2,d)$.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk Thank you that was a very helpful comment, I appreciate it.

Comment: @PeterKravchuk Another question: Is it obvious that "algebra of Hermitian conformal generators is SO(2,d) (even in Euclidean signature)" is true (I mean the part with euclidean signature)? Is there a easy argument so see that?

Comment: @ungerade, when people write conformal algebra in Euclidean signature, they usually have hermitian $D$ and $SO(d)$ rotation generators, but $P^\dagger=K$. So these generators are not hermitian. If you go to a basis in which they are hermitian (by taking combinations like $P+K$ and $i(P-K)$) then you will be able to identify the commutation relations with $SO(2,d)$, not $SO(1,d+1)$. This is because the Hilbert space actually doesn't change under Wick rotation, and so if you had an action of $SO(2,d)$ before the rotation, you will have $SO(2,d)$ action after.

Comment: It is just that the natural basis of generators is not hermitian now, and so this fact is obscured.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate why ⟨0|O(0)O(0)|0⟩=∞ ?